# Maximum audio sampling rate with HDMI output

Tags: audio, hdmi

What is the maximum supported audio sampling rate supported with the Raspberry Pi's HDMI output?  When I play 24 bit, 96KHz tracks in MPD, it appears to be resampling down to 48KHz, as reported by:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card0/pcm0p/sub0/hw_params 
access: RW_INTERLEAVED
format: S16_LE
subformat: STD
channels: 2
rate: 48000 (48000/1)
period_size: 4096
buffer_size: 16384
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [Raspbian kernel source code](https://github.com/digitalcode/android_kernel_raspberrypi/blob/master/sound/arm/bcm2835-pcm.c#L26), you will see that the limit it is set at 48 kHz.

It should be possible to overcome that limit if you modify the `bcm2835-pcm.c` file and recompile the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you know if there are separate limits for analog and HDMI? I believe the DAC only supports 48KHz, so I don't know what would happen if that gets exceeded on analog.

Comment: It's very unlikely that the analogue output has a separate, higher-spec DAC.

Comment: @ElliottB 48 kHz is the max for all sound devices on the Raspberry Pi.  Without recompiling, you can't exceed that for analog or HDMI.

Comment: Right, I got that from your answer syb0rg. What I mean is, if I recompile, increasing HDMI to 192KHz, might that cause problems if some software tries to send 192KHz audio to the analog output?

Comment: @ElliottB I can't say for sure, I haven't tried it.